# Controlling multiple 4066 from single output

Tags: switches, cmos

I'm working on a circuit where I have two 74HC595 in parrallel. (2 serial to parrallel 8bit shift register with latch)

The outputs of the registers are connected to 2 40174 (D type flip flop)
So that allow me to keep the signal up or low until I ask the flip flop to update, even if the register value change and give me an extra control on when I want to apply the changes from the registers.

The flip flops outputs are connected to 4066 switchs. They allow me to "multiplex" 12 data signals.

My question is, can I use a single 40174 pin to control multiple 4066 switchs ?
Do I need to do something special ? (resistor ? capacitor ?) Or can I just wire them as-is ?

40174 Datasheet : http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40174b.pdf

4066 Datasheet : http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf

Comment: Is it too late to switch the 40174 to a 74HC device?

Comment: Absolutely not, it's only on paper/simulator for the moment, but I've read there's not problem mixing both, was it wrong ?

Comment: Can you link datasheets for the particular 4066's and 40174's you're using?

Comment: CD4k have *very* weak drive currents. You should use them only when there's absolutely no other choice.

Comment: @ThePhoton : Added in the question :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : Wasn't aware of that, will try to change the piece asap. But do you know if on the principle this is correct ? What have I to check ? current output of the flipflop regarding the input of the switch control pin ? Voltage ?

Comment: Input current will tell you whether or not it can be done, input capacitance will tell you how long it will take.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There are some 74HC4xxx alternatives, but I don't know which are actually produced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking about is called *fan-out*.

You need to compare the output current capability of the 40174 with the input leakage current of the 4066 control inputs.

I looked at datasheets for some 40174 and 4066 parts from NXP and the 4066 had an input leakage spec of 1 uA, while the 40174 had an ouput drive capability (worst case is sinking current for low output) of 0.4 mA. So you can conceivabley drive quite a few 4066 loads from a 40174. But you didn't say exactly which part numbers you're using, so you need to check your own datsheets.

Also be aware that the more you fan out, the slower the switching transient will be, so you also need to consider the capacitive load of your 4066's and your required switching delay. The 4066 load is about 7.5 pF (max). With 0.5 mA drive this gives a 66 V/us slew rate (very roughly), divided by the number of loads. If you want to switch 5 V in less than 1 us, you can't drive more than about 13 loads. If you want to switch very frequently (e.g. 10,000 switches per second or more) you need to start looking at power handling capabilities of the '174's as well.

**Edit**: looking at the TI datasheets you linked, your parts have similar specs to the NXP parts I looked at.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer ! I need to switch 5V or 3V logic signals (depends which data line), in the worst case every 5 to 10 ms. So according to your explanation that should do the job. Perhap's I sould add some µs of delay between the switching operation and the read/write operations on the µcontroller ?

Comment: "Also be aware that the more you fan out, the slower the switching transient will be" are you referring to the fan out of the driver or the load?

Comment: @jippie, fan-out means a driver driving multiple loads. The more loads you put on the driver, the slower the rising edge of the transition on the connecting net will be. This will delay the load devices acting on the transition, for example by changing the state of their outputs (or switch, in OP's situation).